# design board using dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to make board using dynamoDB.
A post have board name and timeStamp and info.
I want to receive posts sorted by timeStamp in specific board name.
I think model, partition Key is board name, and range key is timestamp.
but same partition key is too often called.
How can I make good model?

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to read this guide:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

for your questions - its depend on how many read/writes.. etc..
i believe this doc can answer your scenario